# How to match values from one dataframe to another in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to match values from one dataframe to another in python.

First dataframe contains rows of 3 columns: User ID, User Name and User Email.
Second dataframe contains rows of 3 columns: Group Name, User ID, User Name.
Third dataframe contains the same colunms as the first only the User ID is different.

The story is the first dataframe contains users with an old ID.
The second are the groups the users of the first dataframe belong to.
The third are the same users only the User ID is different because an API creates a new object and builds a new ID, the Name and Email are like for like values maintained.

What I am trying to achieve is to loop through the second dataframe, get the User ID (which is old), match against the User ID in the first (old), then get the User Name of the dataframe and match against the User Name of the third dataframe to acquire the new User ID.
Then finally create a dataframe like the second, only replacing the User ID (old) with the User ID (new).

I've tried different nested for loops but haven't been able to successfully reference and match.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why the first dataframe is relevant here? `df2['User ID'] = df2['User Name'].map(df3.set_index('User Name')['User ID'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.merge(). This will merge Two DataFrames together by a column to a single DataFrame:

```
df_12 = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['User ID'])
df3 = df3.rename(columns={'User ID':'old User ID')  #in case the column label is in both dataframes the same
df_total = pd.merge(df_12,df3,on=['Username','Group Name']) #returns dataframe with old and new user ID in different columns
```

Then you have all data together in one DataFrame. I think this would be the easiest way.